# No PostgreSQL foreign keys after Rails migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, foreign-keys, database-migration

".references" keyword in Rails migrations does not cause creation of foreign keys in PostgreSQL. How to create them using Rails' means only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails doesn't provide any help with foreign key constraints out of the box.

The [foreigner](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner) gem adds support for foreign keys, although you do need to specify them in addition to saying `t.references :foo`

Answer (score 1):

[Immigrant](https://github.com/jenseng/immigrant) gem can help adding missing foreign keys. Use it with [Foreigner](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner) gem.

Another option is [schema_plus](https://github.com/lomba/schema_plus) gem. It auto-creates foreign keys during migrations.